# In nlsplot(), how to see the model equation in R?

Tags: r, nls

I generated one data

```
nitrogen<- c(0,40,80,120,160,260)
yield <- c(8.4,9.8,10.8,12.5,11.1,12.7)
dataA<- data.frame(nitrogen, yield)
```

and I'd like to see this data as quadratic-plateau model. So I used `nlsplot()` code.

```
install.packages("easynls")
library(easynls)
nlsplot(dataA, model=4)
```

[image]

The model equation is covered in the graph. I'd like to see the full model equation about this quadratic-plateau model.

Could you let me know how to do it?

Always many thanks!!

Comment: Look at `?nlsplot` for help - there is a `position = ` argument to control the location of the equation. Does that help?

Comment: Simply drag your plotting window to make it larger. Your equation should appear if your plotting area is large enough to accommodate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be using par() function to adjust the plot size and font size arguments within par() and then run nlsplot():

```
# change the font size for the plot
par(cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.5, cex=1.2)

# plot the data with formula
nlsplot(dataA, model = 4)
```

[image]
Now I change the font size of the formula to 0.8 to cover better.You can play with the par() arguments to adjust your plot.

```
par(cex.lab = 1, cex.axis = 1, cex=0.8)

nlsplot(dataA, model = 4)
```

[image]